# How to update select tag in parent controller on emitting from child controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to `AngularJS`. In my `parentController` I have added a `div` that contains `select` to get `emloyeeList` from `Database`. And in `childController`, I am creating new `Employee`. After employee created, I want to emit this employee to `parentController` and update `select` tag.

Below is what I tried.

```
mainApp.
controller(
"childController",
['$scope', 'EmployeeFactory', 'CommonFactory', 'EmployeeFactory',
function ($scope, EmployeeFactory, CommonFactory, EmployeeFactory) {
$scope.CreateEmployee = function (newEmployee) {
        var response = EmployeeFactory.CreateEmployee($scope.newEmployee);

        response.success(function (successData) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(successData));

            $scope.GetEmployeeList = function () {
                EmployeeFactory.GetEmployeeList().success(function (data) {
                    alert("empCreated-------emit");
                    $scope.$emit('getEmployeeAfterCreate --- emit-----', { getEmployeeAfterCreate: data });
                }).error(function (data) {
                    alert("getEmpAfterCreate ---- emit-----" + data);
                });
            };

            $scope.GetEmployeeList();
        });
        response.error(function (errorData) {
            alert('ERROR-----------' + errorData);
        });
    };

}]);

mainApp.controller("parentController", ['$scope', 'EmployeeFactory', 'CommonFactory', function ($scope, EmployeeFactory, CommonFactory) {

$scope.employees = {};
$scope.$on('getEmployeeAfterCreate', function (event, args) {
    alert("getEmployeeFrom Create ----------- " + JSON.stringify(args.getEmployeeAfterCreate));
    $scope.employee = args.getEmployeeAfterCreate;

    $scope.employees = {
        ID: $scope.employee.ID,
        FName: $scope.employee.FName,
        LName: $scope.employee.LName,
        Qualifications: $scope.employee.Qualifications,
        Gender: $scope.employee.Gender,
        Phone: $scope.employee.Phone,
        Email: $scope.employee.Email,
        Address: $scope.employee.Address,
        Cities: $scope.employee.Cities
    };
});

}]);
```

Here `EmployeeFactory` and `CommonFactory` are having methods to get and add employees.
Thanks...

Comment: you have `getEmployeeAfterCreate --- emit-----` in your emitter name definition, and you're listening on `getEmployeeAfterCreate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future it might be easier to just post your actual query rather than the whole block but here's you're issue:

You registering the emitter with the name: `getEmployeeAfterCreate --- emit-----` and you're listening on `getEmployeeAfterCreate`. These names need to match otherwise there's really no way to tie the two together.

Simplified example:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("app", []);

mainApp.
controller(
  "childController",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.emitter = function() {
      $scope.$emit('getEmployeeAfterCreate', {
        getEmployeeAfterCreate: {}
      });
    }
  });

mainApp.controller("parentController", function($scope) {

  $scope.$on('getEmployeeAfterCreate', function(event, args) {
    alert("getEmployeeFrom Create ----------- ");
  });
});
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/15304/